# Flutter point to wrong Kotlin version, 1.9.0 instead 1.7.10

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to set up a project and it is giving me the Kotlin compilation error given below.

```
The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

e: /Users/godwin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/mobile_scanner-3.4.1/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/steenbakker/mobile_scanner/utils/YuvToRgbConverter.kt: (70, 24): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1. 

The class is loaded from /Users/name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7d1e949e5931c878951743202d5f3695/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
```

My `buil.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "./plugin.gradle", to: buildscript
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
```

My `flutter doctor -v` out put

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at
      /Users/godwin/fvm/versions/3.7.12
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (5 months ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/godwin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 75.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 232.9559.10

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        •
      android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • iPhone 13 Pro (mobile)      • A0CD816C-4F20-4F4E-A26C-8DE8EC1ACBC7 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile)      • 2649D268-6569-47EF-A961-1CF79E659D07 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.140

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

**What I already tried**

- Cleaning, project including gradle cache on the root and project level.
- I tried creating a new project and it worked perfectly, it downloaded the 1.7.10 kotlin version and also checked with different Kotlin versions and gradle downloading as per the `build.gradle`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

- Tried installing the lower version of Android Studio with lower Kotlin plugin version. Pasting the SS below.

[image: Kotlin plugin version]

Current Android Studio version

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on August 31, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.5.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    Dart (213.7433)
    io.flutter (72.1.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mobile_scanner-3.4.1` requires Kotlin 1.9.0 but you are using 1.7.10.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. You can update the Kotlin plugin to 1.9.0

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
```

2. In case you cannot use Kotlin 1.9.0 due to other incompatibilities you will need to downgrade `mobile_scanner` to such version, which will work with Kotlin 1.9.0.

Comment: I have solved like this. Becuase my project was very big and this was inside in another plugin, very hard to find . Thanks anyway.